# Pause or Delay a loop on a array in a setInterval()

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I want the color of the box I have created to change every 0.5 seconds, I have stored the colors in an array and I want the color to change every .5 seconds but it changes all at once.

```
<style type="text/css">
    #box{
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: green;
    }
</style>

</head>

<body>  
    <div id="box"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var colors = ['red','blue','green','violet','purple'];
        var box = document.getElementById('box');

        setInterval(function(){
            for(var i=0; i < colors.length; i++){
                box.style.backgroundColor=colors[i];
            }   
        }, 300);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on whether you want the box to continue changing after it has been through all the colours, there are a number of ways to solve this:

```js
/*
 Keeps running
*/
var colors = ['red','blue','green','violet','purple'],
    i = 0;

setInterval(function () {
   
  box.style.backgroundColor = colors[i++ % colors.length];
  
}, 500);


/*
 Runs once only
*/
var colorsOnce = colors.slice(),
interval = setInterval(function () {
   
  once.style.backgroundColor = colorsOnce.shift();
  if(!colorsOnce.length) clearInterval(interval);
  
}, 500);
```

```css
.box{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" class="box"></div>
<div id="once" class="box"></div>
```

**Note:** Despite these examples, where timing functions are involved best practice is generally to use a timeout as described by @AmmarCSE above.

Comment: setInterval is best practice. AmmarCSE's setTimeouts are worst practice because he creates many more times scope-bound timers at each point in time than are needed, waisting CPU power and hogging memory. With just 5 colors, there is no noticeable difference. But, with 500,000 colors, [setInterval triumphs](http://jsfiddle.net/xue50c1p/) like a champ while AmmarCSE's solution ["takes 9390ms to load and consumes nearly 500mb of memory."](http://jsfiddle.net/a1otLq89/).

Answer (score 2):

You are looping inside the interval callback, which means that it will go through all the colors each interval.

Make the interval be the loop instead, i.e. go one step furter for each interval. Example:

```
var index = 0;

setInterval(function(){
  box.style.backgroundColor = colors[index];
  index = (index + 1) % colors.length;
},300);
```

Demo:

```js
var colors = ['red','blue','green','violet','purple'];
var box = document.getElementById('box');

var index = 0;

setInterval(function(){
  box.style.backgroundColor = colors[index];
  index = (index + 1) % colors.length;
},300);
```

```css
#box{
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background: green;
        }
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

Note: To actually get an interval that runs every 0.5 seconds, you should use 500 instead of 300 in the `setInterval` call.

Answer (score 1):

Use [**setTimeout()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)

```js
var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'violet', 'purple'];
var box = document.getElementById('box');

for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
  (function(index) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(index);
      box.style.backgroundColor = colors[index];
    }, 300 * i);
  })(i)
}
```

```css
#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

Comment: It does not work and can you show me a way to do it with `setInterval()`

Comment: @amguruprasath, look at Guffas answer

Answer (score 1):

**Two key points you missed in your code**

1. Half a second is "500 milliseconds". So you need to change from 300 ms to 500ms in `setInteval`.
2. When the timer kicks in, you need to update the background color with the "next color in the array".

So you may try something like:

```
var color = 0;
var colors = ['red','blue','green','violet','purple'];
function nextColor(){
    color ++;
    if (color>=colors.length)
        color = 0;
    return colors[color];
}

setInterval(function(){
    box.style.backgroundColor = nextColor();   
},500);
```

This will keep the box changes its color every half a second and cycle through the color array endlessly.